# mysql не использует индексы

Tags: mysql, sql, индексы

есть такой запрос:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT t.number, t.dept_id, d.ls, ue.address, t.isshow, d.`cust-name`, t.status_id, d.subject, t.ticket_id, t.created as cr_tic 
FROM `ost3_ticket` t 
LEFT JOIN `ost3_ticket__cdata` d on (t.`ticket_id` = d.`ticket_id`) 
LEFT JOIN `ost3_user_email` ue on (t.`user_id` = ue.`user_id`) 
WHERE ue.`user_id` = t.`user_id` 
AND (d.`ls` = "123456789" OR ue.`address` = "mail@gmail.com") 
ORDER BY cr_tic desc
```

он показывает такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
таблица тикетов и мейлов не связываются по индексу.

в таблице `ost3_ticket` поле `user_id` указан в качестве индекса,       int(11) UNSIGNED, BTREE.

в таблице `ost3_user_email` поле `user_id` указано точно так же: индекс, int(11) UNSIGNED, BTREE.

при поисках решения узнал что индексы должны быть одинакового типа, но в моём случае не хватает чего то ещё.

из за того что он не связывает таблицы по индексу запрос выполняется ~0.55с, как настроить индексы что бы оптимизировать этот запрос?

Comment: 1) Поскольку в секции WHERE присутствуют условия по полям таблиц `d`  и `ue`, то LEFT JOIN вырождается. Посему начните с замены LEFT JOIN на INNER JOIN. 2) Всё портит OR в секции WHERE. Перепишите на UNION [ALL] двух запросов.

Comment: Сортировка по дате может сильно замедлить запрос. Если таблица большая - и на дату стоит поставить индекс

Answer (score 0):

как отметил Akina, всё портит OR в блоке WHERE, поэтому я решил разбить запрос. конкретно в моей задаче с UNION возникли проблемы, поэтому я сделал 3 разных запроса - первые 2 выбирают ticket_id в соответствии с параметрами (т.е. из 2х условий в WHERE я сделал 2 запроса), а третий - запрос из вопроса в условии которого ticket_id IN(*результаты 2х запросов*). код на php:

```
if($em != ""){
    $oth_t = db_query("SELECT ticket_id FROM `ost3_ticket` ts INNER JOIN `ost3_user_email` ue on (ts.`user_id` = ue.`user_id`) WHERE ue.`address` = \"".$em."\"");
    while($item = db_fetch_array($oth_t)){$tid_emails[] = $item;}
}

if($sls != ""){
    $oth_t = db_query("SELECT ticket_id FROM `ost3_ticket__cdata` WHERE `ls` = \"".$sls."\"");
    while($item = db_fetch_array($oth_t)){$tid_ls[] = $item;}
}

#если хоть один операнд null - итоговый массив будет null, поэтому приведение типов
$tid_all = array_merge((array)$tid_emails, (array)$tid_ls); 
foreach($tid_all as $item){$sql_in .= $item["ticket_id"].",";}

$sql = '
    SELECT t.number, t.dept_id, d.ls, ue.address, t.isshow, d.`cust-name`, t.status_id, d.subject, t.ticket_id, t.created as cr_tic 
    FROM `ost3_ticket` t 
    LEFT JOIN `ost3_ticket__cdata` d on (t.`ticket_id` = d.`ticket_id`) 
    LEFT JOIN `ost3_user_email` ue on (t.`user_id` = ue.`user_id`) 
    WHERE t.ticket_id IN ( '.substr($sql_in, 0, -1).' )
    ORDER BY cr_tic desc
    ';
```